# How to codesign by terminal (IOS Development)

Tags: ios, codesign

`$ codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: XXXXX" --entitlements xxxx.plist  xxxx/Payload/xxxx.app
xxxx/Payload/xxxx.app: replacing existing signature
xxxx/Payload/xxxx.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed`

How can I codesign success?

Thanks

Comment: @ZhanKail check the link in the previous comment a check if the same problem that you have, if not try to edit the question put more information, or image, for the developers and the community can help you. Regards. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Marcos José Pérez Pérez Oh yes. thanks for your help.I slove my problem. But I still don't know the means of  `xattr -cr`.Can you help me ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html

Comment: @Marcos José Pérez Pérez thanks for your answer.